# forcing HTTPS with .htaccess resulting in redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, https

I'm trying to force all users coming to my page access it through https. I have googled a lot and found tons (mostly the same) .htaccess solutions but with all of them I get the "This webpage has a redirect loop Reload" in chrome and similar in firefox.

This is what I have currently in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

[link](http://test.sudec.net) to site.

Can anyone advise what the issue might be because I have no idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]
```

Just make sure this is **very first rule** in your .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error. There is nothing else in .htaccess file so I'm sure its the first rule. Are there any settings for apache that might prevent this from executing?

Comment: Looks like you're using `nginx` not Apache. I don't know if this exact rule syntax is good for `nginx` also.

Comment: Also verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: I do get internal server error when putting some garbage in `.htaccess`. I was using it previously so it should work. Its just this rewrite that doesn't want to cooperate

Comment: ok if you comment out this rule does this redirect loop goes away?

Comment: yes. well there is nothing else at the moment but I was trying also to remove www if the user would enter it (www.example.com rewrite to example.com) and that worked fine.